# How cache works in Symfony 2 DIC and how can I use it?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I can't find any tutorial or useful information about caching the configuration of a bundle.

Basically my bundle loads a lot (20+) of tagged services. Can I use cache to speed up the compiler pass? How the cache should work? The only little piece of information I can find is [Dumping the Configuration for Performance](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#dumping-the-configuration-for-performance).

Answer (score 1):

For sure you're using an APC cache right so further you can cache in memcached/redis popular query results(like prepopulated lists, categories and stuff).

For further optimizations check this presentation:

http://slides.seld.be/?file=2011-10-20+High+Performance+Websites+with+Symfony2.html#1

It really rocks your world!

Comment: I appreciate your link to that lecture, but I was talking about the configuration caching...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you read the components section, beware that some of the information will be aimed for people using the components outside of the framework.

From the link you posted:

```
In the full stack framework the compilation and caching
of the container is taken care of for you.
```

Comment: So, what really is "dumping the container"?

Comment: @Gremo If you are using the full stack framework, it is "dumping the container" into app/cache. It is one of the many things that gets cached automatically and you don't have to worry about. Just check the app/cache directory, lots of other components store things there too to speed things up.